# Erro ao instalar programas no windows 10

Tags: windows, instalador

Tentei instalar o editor de text Atom.io e deu o erro:

> 2017-04-16 13:25:15> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
>   2017-04-16 13:25:15> Program: Starting install, writing to
>   C:\Users\Icaro\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp 2017-04-16 13:25:15>
>   Program: About to install to: C:\Users\Icaro\AppData\Local\atom
>   2017-04-16 13:25:16> Unhandled exception: System.AggregateException:
>   Um ou mais erros. ---> System.ArgumentException: Caracteres inválidos
>   no caminho.    em System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path,
>   Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
>   em System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32
>   maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)    em
>   System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)    em
>   System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()    em
>   Squirrel.SingleGlobalInstance..ctor(String key, TimeSpan timeOut)
>   em Squirrel.UpdateManager.b__32_0()    em
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    em
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Depois tentei instalar um jogo e deu:

> "O caminho para a pasta ""C:" contém um caractere inválido

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Tenta instalar de outro usuário e vê se dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Eu tentei, e o erro continuou. Andei pesquisando e acredito que sejam problemas no registro. Tentei apagar todos os registros relacionados aos programas, mas ainda assim o erro permanece. Algumas dicas foram consertar os caminhos errados, mas não sei fazer isso .